# Add rows to data frame by filling in sequence and repeating values

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
originalID <- c('A','A','B','B','B','B')
newID <- c('D','G','R','Q','N','P')
newTime <- c(2,4,3,6,7,10)

x <- data.frame(originalID, newID, newTime)

x
  originalID newID newTime
1          A     D       2
2          A     G       4
3          B     R       3
4          B     Q       6
5          B     N       7
6          B     P      10
```

My desired result is a data frame that looks like this:

```
   originalID newID newTime
1           A     A       0
2           A     A       1
3           A     D       2
4           A     D       3
5           A     G       4
6           B     B       0
7           B     B       1
8           B     B       2
9           B     R       3
10          B     R       4
11          B     R       5
12          B     Q       6
13          B     N       7
14          B     N       8
15          B     N       9
16          B     P      10
```

Basically, I'm trying to fill in the sequence before and between each value of `newTime`, starting from 0 and ending at the max value of `newTime` for each `originalID`. I want to repeat the values of the other columns, except from 0 to the first `newTime`, for which I want to repeat the value from the `originalID`.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ~(PS also, add `stringsAsFactors=F` in your df)

Data Input

```
x <- data.frame(originalID, newID, newTime,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

---

Solution

```
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
x=x %>% group_by(originalID) %>% complete(newTime=full_seq(0:max(newTime),1))
x=x %>% group_by(originalID)%>%mutate(newID=zoo::na.locf(newID,na.rm = F))

x$newID[is.na(x$newID)]=x$originalID[is.na(x$newID)]

x
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   originalID [2]
   originalID newTime newID
        <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
 1          A       0     A
 2          A       1     A
 3          A       2     D
 4          A       3     D
 5          A       4     G
 6          B       0     B
 7          B       1     B
 8          B       2     B
 9          B       3     R
10          B       4     R
11          B       5     R
12          B       6     Q
13          B       7     N
14          B       8     N
15          B       9     N
16          B      10     P
```